# Conditional Inside A Foreach Loop To Filter Value And Have A Fall Back

Tags: if-statement, multidimensional-array, foreach, filtering, conditional-statements

I have a strange problem and I can't get my head around it. I have tried loads of different ways to get the desired result but with no success. What I am looking for is a set of rules like fall backs if conditions are met in a loop. So this is what I have done so far but have tried multitude of different ways. I am always getting fallback as the match even though country, postcode and shipping method is defined. It is almost like it's ignoring these values.

If someone can point me to the right direction I would be grateful thanks.

```
$country        = 'GB';
$postCode       = "LE5";
$shippingMethod = "subscription_shipping";

$shippingMatrix = array(
    array(
        "country"            => "GB",
        "isPostCodeExcluded" => "LE5",
        "shippingMethod"     => "subscription_shipping",
        "carrier"            => "Royal Mail",
        "carrierService"     => "Royal Mail",
    ),
    array(
        "country"            => "GB",
        "isPostCodeExcluded" => false,
        "shippingMethod"     => "subscription_shipping",
        "carrier"            => "DHL",
        "carrierService"     => "DHL",
    ),
    array(
        "country"            => false,
        "isPostCodeExcluded" => false,
        "shippingMethod"     => "subscription_shipping",
        "carrier"            => "Fallback",
        "carrierService"     => "Fallback",
    ),
    array(
        "country"            => "GB",
        "isPostCodeExcluded" => false,
        "shippingMethod"     => "standard_delivery",
        "carrier"            => "DPD",
        "carrierService"     => "DPD",
    ),
);

$carriers = [];
foreach ($shippingMatrix as $matrix) {
    // If only Shipping Method is matched then fall back will be the result
    if ($shippingMethod === $matrix['shippingMethod']) {
        $carriers = [
            $matrix['carrier'],
            $matrix['carrierService'],
        ];
        // If only Shipping Method & Country is matched then fall back will be the result DHL
        if ($country === $matrix['country']) {
            $carriers = [
                $matrix['carrier'],
                $matrix['carrierService'],
            ];
            // If only Shipping Method & Country & PostCode is matched then fall back will be the result Royal Mail
            if ($postCode === $matrix['isPostCodeExcluded']) {
                $carriers = [
                    $matrix['carrier'],
                    $matrix['carrierService'],
                ];
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($carriers);
```

Answer (score 0):

**$carriers** variable not used as an array notation and because of that 
 values are overridden. All you need to do to transform **$carriers** to **$carriers[]** .

Here is example below.

```
$carriers[]  = [
            $matrix['carrier'],
            $matrix['carrierService'],
          ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply but this wasn't necessary. After a good old think I made the novice mistake of mixing my types up.

```
$carriers = [];
foreach ($shippingMatrix as $matrix) {
    if ($shippingMethod === $matrix['shippingMethod'] && $country === $matrix['country']) {
        if ($postCode === $matrix['isPostCodeExcluded']) {
            $carriers = [
                $matrix['carrier'],
                $matrix['carrierService'],
            ];
        }
    }

    if ($shippingMethod === $matrix['shippingMethod'] && $country !== $matrix['country'] && !$country) {
        $carriers = [
            $matrix['carrier'],
            $matrix['carrierService'],
        ];
    }
}
```